Blowing up capacitors with a 9v battery

Hello, I have a 9V battery I would like to blow up some capacitors with; currently I have 6.3v 180uF capacitors that don't seem to blow up at least in a good time(I'm aiming for <5 seconds), they just get slightly warm.
So is there any way I could blow up some capacitors with decent explosions using a 9V battery? Would using a 2V or 4V rated cap work?
I could also use a booster module to achieve 12V but I'm afraid the large current an exploding capacitors makes will damage the module.
Thanks.

Using a lower voltage rating cap will certainly help the process. A physically small cap would help as well. Also, make sure you apply the voltage across it in reverse. You still may have trouble  "blowing it up" with a 9v battery as the current is limited, therfore your energy per unit time is limited.
It's best to use a higher voltage higher current source. You could consider jacking the voltage up with a boost converter and storing the charge in a much larger, higher voltage cap. And then blasting your DUT.
But to guarantee destruction, just put AC mains across the terminals. You will be popping in milliseconds.
Although the advice I provided is technically correct for your "application", it's best you just watch some youtube videos of "basement scientists" perform this stunt.

Suggestions for Darwin Awards try-outs?

I would advise against blowing up a capacitor unless you know what you're doing.
A 9 V battery doesn't have enough oomph to blow an electrolytic capacitor.
What type of capacitor are you trying to blow up? You need a lot of current to cause an aluminum electrolytic capacitor to blow (perhaps greater than 10 amps). Blowing up electrolytic capacitors can cause bits and pieces to fly about which is a safety hazard, especially eye damage. Larger capacitors can cause blunt force trauma as demonstrated in a high school electronics class (demonstration by our instructor in a controlled environment).
Ceramic capacitors will crack.
Aluminum electrolytic capacitors may blow their guts out and spray out fluff and electrolyte which may not be healthy for you, or, ooze goo after the safety seal ruptures. This is from first hand experience.
Dry (solid) tantalum  capacitors generally crack in my experience repairing equipment with failed tantalums.

Given enough overvoltage, tantalums will blow up, complete with burning bits of tantalum and/or plastic.  People gave me a lot of room in the electronics lab after that day...

Ah, youth...
Electrolytic capacitors 'blow up' when they fail in a shorted condition. One failure cause is being exposed to higher-than-rated voltage. Another way is to connect them in reverse. Either way, once this happens, the current begins to flow across the short, heating up the capacitor, something which which you seem to have observed already.
Stand-up (radial) electrolytic caps have scribe lines in the top that allow the cap to 'vent' when it fails. This allows the pressure to escape, so they don't explode (usually.) Instead, they sort of 'fizz' as they electrolyte heats up and vaporizes, which vents out the top by breaking through the scribe. Hit them with enough energy and they will 'spill their guts' as the electrolyte and foil are ejected from the casing.
Now, why didn't your cap do that? 9V batteries don't supply a lot of current. This limits the amount of heating that will occur across the failed cap. So your cap won't heat enough to do anything interesting. But, you will have destroyed the cap anyway (check it with a voltmeter.)
You'll have more... dramatic results with a battery that can provide more power (current, really), such as a 12V automotive type.
Nevertheless, please use caution. Eye protection strongly recommended. Putting the cap under a plastic shield while you do this is also a good idea. Avoid breathing the emitted fumes as they're irritating and toxic.
